# react-router-dom does not work in web

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I installed react-router-dom, and works fine in internal server, but when I upload the build version to my server does not redirect and seems like the url does not exist.

Please Help!

Comment: What kind of server are you using in production?

Comment: Keep in mind React is a Javascript Library. It only works if the user has landed on the index.html. On the development, all your requests goes to index.html, however, on the production, your server points to different paths based on the your params. You need to force all your requests to point to index.html so you can get your router working fine.

Comment: @jameslafferty Im using a apache server

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link to a credible .htaccess template:
https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/blob/master/app/.htaccess

You'd want to put this in the same directory you're serving from. This is necessary to have apache correctly route calls. Alternatively, you could use HashRouter, which would work but would result in less pretty urls.